# Showing that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, recursion

Let $(x_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ a sequence, such :

$$x_1=1 \; \text{and} \; x_{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1} (x_n)^2, \; n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Show that $x_n \xrightarrow{ n \to \infty} 0$.

I have no idea how I would prove this? I mean the sequence is clearly decreasing but I don't know where to go from there?

Comment: Find the missing word: “A sequence that is decreasing and ____ is convergent.”

Comment: @MartinR bounded below but that doesn’t specifically give me that the limit is equal to 0

Comment: Exactly. So you know that the sequence is convergent. What can you conclude about the limit value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence is decreasing and bounded below (by zero), and therefore convergent: $a = \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n$ exists.

Now consider the identity $$x_{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1} x_n^2 \,.$$ For $n \to \infty$, the left-hand side converges to $a$, and the right-hand side converges to $a^2$.

It follows that $a = a^2$, so that $a=0$ or $a=1$ are the only possible limits. The latter is not possible because $x_n \le \frac 12$ for $n \ge 2$.

Comment: Where does the a=a^2 come from?

Comment: @Mathissohardlmao: See updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

For each $n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}$, $x_n<{x_{n-1}}^2$. Since $x_2=\frac12$, it follows that $x_n\leqslant\frac1{2^{n-1}}$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: where did 1/2^(n-1) come from?

Comment: You know that $x_2=\frac12=\frac1{2^{2-1}}$, right?! But then $x_3<\left(\frac12\right)^2=\frac1{2^2}=\frac1{2^{3-1}}$, $x_4<\frac1{2^4}<\frac1{2^{4-1}}$ and so on...